# How can I confirm that burn process was completed successfully?

Tags: windows, burning, compact-disc, nero

Just now I tried to make a duplicate copy of my Windows XP Pro SP3 CD.
I had set 32X speed while the max speed allowed is 48X. And checked "Verify the Data after burning".

I didn't observe how much % did it complete. But after 15 mins (which is sufficient period to burn disc), I heard "Fatal Error" sound. When I saw the monitor, There was a message box which was showing "Error while burning Disc", I saved the error log which you can find here [click_me](http://sites.Google.com/site/aravindspattar/Log.txt).

How do I acknowledge that burning process is done??

Well. my PC is able to read the CD and CD is bootable too..

I am not sure .. whether the burning process got failed or the verify Process!

Please let me know if you have come across or aware of  such situation ..
As it is XP installation CD .. I don't want to do trial and error method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your logs seem to suggest things failed while burning in a few minutes.

This is when the burn started,

```
8:59:08 PM  #16 Phase 36 File dlgbrnst.cpp, Line 1730
    Burn process started at 32x (4,800 KB/s)
```

This is when the first burn error is logged,

```
9:01:57 PM  #23 CDR -1135 File Writer.cpp, Line 302
    Write error
    I: SONY DVD RW AW-G170A
```

Burn was given up at this point,

```
9:01:57 PM  #25 Phase 38 File dlgbrnst.cpp, Line 1730
    Burn process failed at 32x (4,800 KB/s)
```

---

You may want to check this [AfterDawn thread](http://forums.afterdawn.com/thread_view.cfm/406343).
Look at suggestions in the reply posting.
<sup>Nero version in that case seems to be older than yours, so look at the other points.</sup>

Comment: So my disc is gone !!
thanks for the response :) regards,